Safari won't load intranet pages
My Safari won't load certain pages sometimes:

Safari doesn't load the page and says the server isn't responding
The pages are all on intranet, no internet sites are affected
It happens on macOS and iOS - separate devices (so it's not device related)
It doesn't happen on Firefox (Focus) on the same device (so it's not a network problem)
The page loads consistently when I quit Safari on iOS, but only one page (another page doesn't work)
I'm not sure what triggered it, but it coincides with a network layout change where I removed my ISP's router and used PPPoE on my own router (previously my own router was in DMZ of the ISP router and that ISP router was doing PPPoE)

I cleared the website data but that didn't work. Restarting my phone didn't work either. Any other ideas what this might be? Could it be HSTS pinning, or some SSL certificate cache broken (but then why does quitting safari work?)?

Ok after trying some more settings it turns out it's 'Use advanced tracking and fingerprint protection'. The hostnames I use had dual DNS resolution (i.e. LAN from LAN, but WAN IP from WAN, as alternative to hairpin NAT), and maybe that causes a conflict.
It turns out this setting overrides DNS, hence my LAN websites don't resolve anymore. New question: how can I use this protection while still using my own DNS?
